# Redux and periodic actions

Tags: javascript, flux, redux, periodicity

To illustrate the [use-case](https://jsbin.com/mitegojoli/edit?js,console,output), I have a `</video>` tag that dispatches an action every time (`~250ms`) the playhead moves. I'm not a Flux/Redux's guru and I'm facing some issues:

- Is it a valid approach ?
- With a weighty state, may it cause performance issues ?
- Do you have any optimisation proposals about subscribing to a part of the state changes ?

Many many thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach is reasonable (especially if you are wanting to use information from that video element across the application), and depending on the app/actions, there may be consequences.

If you are using React with Redux, the `connect` higher-order component can take a `pure: true` option to do a shallow compare of props in the `shouldComponentUpdate` callback that might help prevent too many re-renders.

Otherwise you could use a store enhancer or higher-order reducer to specially handle the actions fired by the video element. The [redux-ignore middleware](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-ignore) may help with that or provide a pattern for doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer ! As a side note for people having the same questions, https://github.com/andrewngu/sound-redux will give you some additional info.